# How to perform an action every 12 hours?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have orders table `ord` as following:

```
orderid orderstatus orderdate                          num
12         2         2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171         0
13         1         2015-09-01 17:25:12.237141         0
```

I need to write a function that gets all orders in `orderstatus = 2`, and do insert to table `A` every 12 hours. The thing is that I want this insert to be done once every 12 hours... the `num` indecates how many times I did insert to table `A`.

so basicly it should have this logic:

```
time passed < 12     num = 0  OK.
12<time passed<24    num = 0  do insert to table A.  num = 1 OK.
24 time passed<36    num = 1  do insert to table A.  num = 2 OK.
....
```

I wrote the following code which will be invoked every hour to check if insert needs to be done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    ROW record;
    v_time int;
begin   
for row in 
    Select  orderid,orderdate,num
    From ord
    where orderstatus=2
loop 

    SELECT (extract(epoch from localtimestamp - ROW.orderdate::timestamp)/3600)::integer into v_time;

     if.........
         insert into A
         update ord set num = num+1 where orderid=ROW.orderid

end loop;
return;   
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

The thing is that I have no idea how to write the `if` in the function.

any idea how to write the condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really use Postgres, I use SQL Server, but it seems that they both support similar feature set, so I'll "convert" how I'd do it SQL Server into Postgres syntax. I may end up having some syntax errors.

**Main idea**

- You don't really need explicit `IF` and you don't need to process individual rows one-by-one in a loop. Do the necessary checks in the set-based `WHERE` condition of the `UPDATE` statement.
- Instead of having a `num` column have a column `last_inserted_datetime` that would hold a timestamp of last insert. Initially it will be `NULL`.
- Have one set-based `UPDATE` statement that can be run as often as you want during 12 hours, but it would actually change the `last_inserted_datetime` only if 12 hours have passed. If you for some reason do not run this statement at all for more than 24 hours it is still OK, it would `UPDATE` in 12 hour increments. So, if the procedure didn't run for, say, 37 hours, just run it three times to catch up.
- Use [`RETURNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-update.html) clause to do both `UPDATE` of `ord` table and `INSERT` into `A` table in one statement and only if `UPDATE` actually changed any rows. It is not clear what exactly you are inserting into `A`. Adjust the query below as needed.

Put this query in a stored procedure and schedule it to run periodically (say, once an hour or more often).

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    UPDATE ord
    SET last_inserted_datetime = 
        COALESCE(last_inserted_datetime, orderdate) + interval '12 hours'
    WHERE
        orderstatus = 2
        AND (now() - COALESCE(last_inserted_datetime, orderdate)) > interval '12 hours'
    RETURNING orderid, orderdate, last_inserted_datetime
)
INSERT INTO A (orderid, orderdate, last_inserted_datetime)
SELECT orderid, orderdate, last_inserted_datetime
FROM CTE
;
```

Let's see how it works. We start with this `ord` table:

```
orderid orderstatus orderdate                   last_inserted_datetime
12      2           2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171  NULL
13      1           2015-09-01 17:25:12.237141  NULL
```

Let `now` be `2015-09-01 18:00:00`, and we run the query above. The difference between `now` and `orderdate` is less than 12 hours, so no rows would be updated, no rows would be inserted into `A`.

Wait till `now` is `2015-09-02 06:00:00`, and run the query above. The difference between `now` and `COALESCE(last_inserted_datetime, orderdate)` is more than 12 hours for `orderid=12`, so this row would be updated.

```
last_inserted_datetime = 2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171 + 12 hrs = 2015-09-02 05:23:58.189171
```

Note, that `last_inserted_datetime` is not set to `now`, it is set to `orderdate` plus 12 hours.

`ord` table becomes:

```
orderid orderstatus orderdate                   last_inserted_datetime
12      2           2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171  2015-09-02 05:23:58.189171
13      1           2015-09-01 17:25:12.237141  NULL

Plus one row is inserted into `A`.
```

Wait till `now` is `2015-09-02 18:00:00`, and run the query above. The difference between `now` and `COALESCE(last_inserted_datetime, orderdate)` is more than 12 hours for `orderid=12`, so this row would be updated.

`ord` table becomes:

```
orderid orderstatus orderdate                   last_inserted_datetime
12      2           2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171  2015-09-02 17:23:58.189171
13      1           2015-09-01 17:25:12.237141  NULL

Plus one row is inserted into `A`.
```

Imagine the scheduler failed for two days and didn't execute the query until `now` is `2015-09-04 18:00:00`.

`ord` table becomes:

```
orderid orderstatus orderdate                   last_inserted_datetime
12      2           2015-09-01 17:23:58.189171  2015-09-03 05:23:58.189171
13      1           2015-09-01 17:25:12.237141  NULL

Plus one row is inserted into `A`.
```

Note, that `last_inserted_datetime` was incremented only by 12 hours. Run the query again and it will increment again and again until it catches up with current time. So, none of the updates/inserts would be missed.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can write something similar to:

```
...
SELECT (extract(epoch from localtimestamp - ROW.orderdate::timestamp)/3600)::integer into v_time;
IF FOUND THEN
   -- begin code from your last code snippet
   insert into A 
   update ord set num = num+1 where orderid=ROW.orderid
   -- end 
ELSE
   ...
END IF;
...
```

In more details you can check [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) about control structures.

Comment: mmm but the query always return value... it return the diffrance in hours.. it always will be something...